# How to create edge label in Arangodb?

Tags: arangodb

java-driver 4.1.10 I've created database named mydatabase1 I've created a graph using Java so my question is that how to set edge label using Java code?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean with "edge label" a field in an edge-document, you can set it when you call `insertEdge` like in the code below.

```
ArangoDB arangoDB = new ArangoDB.Builder().build();

// create database
arangoDB.createDatabase("myDatabase");

// create named graph
Set<EdgeDefinition> edgeDefinitions = Collections.singleton(
  new EdgeDefinition().collection("myEdgeCollection").from("myVertexCollection").to("myVertexCollection"));
arangoDB.db("myDatabase").createGraph("myGraph", edgeDefinitions);

// create from vertex
BaseDocument from = new BaseDocument("myFromKey");
arangoDB.db("myDatabase").graph("myGraph").vertexCollection("myVertexCollection").insertVertex(from);

// create to vertex
BaseDocument to = new BaseDocument("myToKey");
arangoDB.db("myDatabase").graph("myGraph").vertexCollection("myVertexCollection").insertVertex(to);

// create edge
BaseEdgeDocument edge = new BaseEdgeDocument("myVertexCollection/myFromKey",
    "myVertexCollection/myToKey");
edge.addAttribute("label", "value");
edge.addAttribute("whatever", 42);
arangoDB.db("myDatabase").graph("myGraph").edgeCollection("myEdgeCollection").insertEdge(edge);
```

Instead of using `BaseEdgeDocument` you can also use `Map<String, Object>`

```
Map<String, Object> edge = new HashMap<String, Object>();
edge.put("_from", "myVertexCollection/myFromKey");
edge.put("_to", "myVertexCollection/myToKey");
edge.put("label", "value");
edge.put("whatever", 42);
arangoDB.db("myDatabase").graph("myGraph").edgeCollection("myEdgeCollection").in sertEdge(edge);
```

or create your own POJO representing your edge. The edge needs at least the fields `_from` and `_to`. If you don't want to name the fields in your POJO _from and _to, you can use the annotation `DocumentField` with the values `Type.FROM` and `Type.TO` on two `String` fields of your choice.

```
public class MyEdge {
  @DocumentField(Type.FROM)
  private String from;

  @DocumentField(Type.TO)
  private String to;

  public MyEdge() {}

  ..setter & getter
}
```

Comment: which version is stable because i can't find a class like ArangoDB in arangodb-java-driver version 4.1.10

Comment: 4.1.10 is the last stable version (released today). It includes the class `ArangoDB`. Maybe you get the wrong version?
http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.arangodb%7Carangodb-java-driver%7C4.1.10%7Cjar

Comment: how to create edge label in arangodb-java-driver version 3.0.0

Comment: Thank you for your help as you mentioned above I've created a label on edge but i can't see the label on graph  in arangodb web interface how can i see the label which I've created

Comment: The graph-viewer has settings (right top corner) in which you can set the name of the edge label attribute (in your case `label`).